# How to remove double quotes without escape (^) in cmd/ batchfile?

Tags: windows, cmd, command-line, ui-automation

Note: as the OP is a new user, I'm editing the question with reproducible details so that it doesn't get closed. It's a good question, but was originally confusing.

The Windows username is: jhon^smith

```
ECHO %username%
output : jhonsmith
```

My expectation:

```
jhon^smith
```

---

If I use:

```
echo "%username%"
```

then the output is:

```
"jhon^smith"
```

How can I remove the double quotes but keep the caret, which is actually part of the username?

Comment: One solution for usage in a batch file is: `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion & echo !username!& endlocal` and directly in a command prompt window `%ComSpec% /V:ON /C echo !username!` or even better `for %I in ("%username%") do @echo %~I`

Comment: I have to add that even better would be `%ComSpec% /D /V:ON /C echo !username!` to make sure that an `AutoRun` registry value does not effect the output of the environment variable value. Further I have to add that `for %I in ("%username%") do @echo %~I` could cause in letters change their case if there is by chance a file or directory in current directory with same string as the string value of `username` as the usage of `%~I` results in accessing the file system and use the string of by chance found file/directory instead of the exact string of environment variable `username`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
for /f %a in ("%username%") do echo %a
```

output:

```
jhon^smith
```

(btw: It should be spelt `john^smith` but never mind.)

Explanation:

In the command `echo %username%`, `cmd.exe` replaces `%username%` with its actual content, so the command becomes `echo jhon^smith`. This is then parsed, the the `^` is processed as the escape character, so it replaces `^s` with `s`.

In the command `for /f %a in ("%username%") do echo %a`, the quoted string is treated as a string without the quotes, and no parsing of `^` is performed. Type `for /?` for more details.

Comment: If the environment variable `username` is defined in the command prompt window with `set "username=Clark Kent & Lois Lane ^!"` this command line outputs just `Clark` instead of `Clark Kent & Lois Lane ^!`. I posted in my comment below the question the better solutions. The command line in the question could be modified to `for /F delims^=^ eol^= %I in ("%username%") do echo %I` to work for all `username` string values not containing `"`.